# Understanding certain limited biochemical impacts of egg yolk

Tags: human-physiology, food, digestion, eggs, food-chemistry

I am researching the use of isolated egg yolk lecithin (EYL) in food preparation. I am interested in its ability to act as an emulsifier without having ancillary negative impacts. I am aware that some people have negative dietary reactions - intolerance (as a separate issue from allergic reaction) to egg yolks. So my question is whether the components in isolated EYL are the same ones that typically result in dietary intolerance or are there other, different components in "natural" egg yolks that might be a cause, where EYL might typically be clear of them.

In attempting to research this on the Internet I have found few details on the chemicals/compounds in egg yolks, let alone which are prone to dietary intolerance. Most of the material I find deals with egg allergies (frequently lumped together as related to "whole eggs, egg yolks, or egg whites"). There are some articles specific to egg whites because of their use in vaccines. That, however, is not helpful for my question, both because of their focus on egg albumin and the allergy issue rather than intolerance from ingestion.

As I had a previous question "closed" for being "off-topic" because appearing to seek answers to medical questions, I want to clarify that I am only after greater granularity concerning egg yolk composition and digestibility so I can do further research.

Comment: You'll need to identify research indicating that a phenomenon of egg yolk intolerance that is not an allergy 1) exists, and 2) is sufficiently well-defined to attempt to find a mechanism. Otherwise there is no biological question to answer.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan Krause. I now understand how to reformat the question.

Comment: I would also consider moving your post to SE Biomedical Sciences where I imagine people are more familiar with the medical conditions you mention.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @David